# Invoking bearer token validation from a custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, custom-attributes, bearer-token

I have an MVC/Angular application which implements cookie based identity authentication to have a single mechanism to authorize/authenticate users regardless of whether the controller action returns an MVC page or Json result. For simplicity, my web api projects are part of the web solution so that they can be easily deployed all at once.
Now I have a vendor that wants to make json or possibly xml requests for data. 
I am using WebApi 2 and MVC 5
So I will need to create another API. My requirements are

1. Host the Api within the website for ease of deployment
2. Secure the Api with Bearer tokens
3. Make no other code changes
   I can't suppress cookies for API requests as I would need to make changes to every callback (the client scripts are not very centralized... we were learning Angular as we were building the site)
   Since this vendor is only requesting data, I can bypass using the Authorize attribute and create a custom attribute derived from AuthorizationFilterAttribute for vendor only Api calls. I also have a simple authorization server provider derived from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.
   I can create a token and send it back to my custom filter as a bearer token in the auth header with no problem. My question is now what? Do I need to create a per request instance of my class derived from OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider and call an override on that class to authenticate? (I am using StructureMap)
   Or is there another way that I am just missing. I can find a million examples of creating a filter to handle basic authentication, but everything about bearer I have found so far uses the katana pipeline to validate the bearer token

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought. By adding a custom Authorization attribute to the endpoints that required bearer tokens.

```
[BearerTokenAuthorizationFilter(Role = "Vendor")]
   [Route("api/v1/purchaseorders/{records:int?}")]
   [ResponseType(typeof(Dictionary<string, VendorPurchaseOrder>))]
   public IHttpActionResult GetNewPurchaseOrders(int records = 0)
```

This ignored the cookie completely.